# Why does this substitution not work?

Tags: matrix, replacement, pattern-matching

```
Sqrt[Matrix[( {
     {0, 1},
     {-1, 0}
    } )]] /. f_[Matrix[x__]] :> Matrix[MatrixFunction[f, x]]
```

`Matrix` is an undefined symbol but I want to define some substitutions with it.

Comment: For those searching for a similar question in the future please make the title more informative. For example " function substitution not matching with Sqrt"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume this is related to that other question you recently posted--maybe merge them? Anyway, I'm going to change MatrixFunction for now to hopefully get a clearer answer. Your pattern matched an expression whose body only had one argument. You need to add something to the pattern to match more arguments. Try something like this:

```
Sqrt[Matrix[({{0, 1}, {-1, 0}})]] /. 
  f_[Matrix[mat_], args___] :> Matrix[MatrixFunction[f[#, args] &, mat]]
```

`Matrix[MatrixFunction[Sqrt[#1] & , {{0, 1}, {-1, 0}}]]`

(Thanks BobHanlon)

Comment: What is `MatrixFn`?

Comment: The RHS of the rule should be `Matrix[MatrixFn[f[#, args]&, mat]]`

Comment: @BobHanlon thanks, works!

Comment: @Anixx, I don't know what to expect from MatrixFunction, so I chose something else to make verifying the result easier. As it turns out, I still screwed that up because I forgot it was the f that needed to be applied.

Comment: Thanks @BobHanlon!

Comment: Your welcome, but your edit didn't change the rule and may cause some confusion if the rule is left as is.

Comment: omg. I copy/pasted the wrong thing.

Comment: FWIW, I don't mind if people just edit mistakes.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the `FullForm` of `Sqrt`, you see that it is silently converted to a `Power`, a function taking two arguments, not one.  Your pattern only matches functions of a single argument.

```
FullForm[Sqrt[x]]
(* Power[x, Rational[1, 2]]*)
```

Answer (score 1):

As explained by @Mikado `Sqrt` is converted to `Power` which takes two arguments. One solution is to define:

```
sqrt=Inactive[Sqrt]
```

and then use `sqrt` instead like

```
sqrt[Matrix[({{0, 1}, {-1, 0}})]] /. 
 f_[Matrix[x__]] :> Matrix[MatrixFunction[Activate@f, x]]
```

If it is too late and you already used `Sqrt` at multiple parts in the notebook then you can use:

```
Hold[Sqrt[Matrix[({{0, 1}, {-1, 0}})]]] /. 
  f_[Matrix[x__]] :> Matrix[MatrixFunction[f, x]] // ReleaseHold
```

Or

```
Sqrt[Matrix[({{0, 1}, {-1, 0}})]] /. Sqrt[s_] -> Inactive[Sqrt][s]  /. 
 f_[Matrix[x__]] :> Matrix[MatrixFunction[Activate@f, x]]
```

**Notice** that I used `Sqrt[s_] -> Inactive[Sqrt][s]` instead of `Sqrt -> Inactive[Sqrt]` because I am allowing `Sqrt[s_]` to be converted to

`Power[Pattern[s,Blank[]],Rational[1,2]]`

If I had a bad idea and used `HoldPattern` :

```
Sqrt[Matrix[({{0, 1}, {-1, 0}})]] /. 
 HoldPattern[Sqrt[s_]] -> Inactive[Sqrt][s]
```

Then it would not work because It would not convert to `Power`. If the `Sqrt` was a `Cos` then `HoldPattern` would work :

```
Cos[Matrix[({{0, 1}, {-1, 0}})]] /. 
     HoldPattern[Cos[s_]] -> Inactive[Cos][s]
```

because there is nothing to worry about concerning hidden transformations in that case (there can be in other cases because of the parity of `Cos` which leads to argument reordering).